# Multiple sheets writting to a single master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, synchronization, google-sheets-api

I have two user input sheets, in which users can enter data in row 2.
This data is then copied over to the master once the save button is pressed.
The script I've written to do all this works fine, my concern comes down to the moment both of these user input sheets are being used at the same time.

Is there a chance that if the both users save their data simultaneously or close to, there could be an overight of the data in the master sheet??

Would I be better off implementing the use of [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)?
I'm unfamiliar with its use, answers please include how to incorporate it into the current script.

My code looks as follows:

```
function submitData() {
  var activeSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputSheet = activeSheet.getActiveSheet();                //source sheet
  var dataSheet  = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Master");        //destination sheet
  
   if( inputSheet == "Usuario 1" || "Usuario 2") {              //check its the right sheet
    var rol = inputSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();             //check if Rol is empty, if so text box warning
    if(!rol){
      Browser.msgBox("Ingrese numero de Rol antes de guardar");
    }else{
      var maxCol = inputSheet.getMaxColumns();   //max columns
      var rolData = inputSheet.getRange(2,1,1,maxCol).getValues();      //get Row data

      //Create history reference in input sheet  
      inputSheet.insertRowsAfter(5, 1);                                   //insert new row in input
      inputSheet.getRange(6,1,1,maxCol).setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);  // change row colour to white
      inputSheet.getRange(6,1,1,maxCol).setValues(rolData);               //copy data from row 2 to 6
      
      //Lock from here on??
      var blankRow = dataSheet.getLastRow()+1;    //identify the next blank row in Master
      var masterRow = dataSheet.getRange(blankRow,1,1,maxCol);  //destination range
      dataSheet.insertRowsAfter(blankRow-1, 1);             //insert new row in Master
      inputSheet.getRange(2,1,1,maxCol).copyTo(masterRow);  //copy rol data to master
      inputSheet.getRange('A2:BA2').clearContent();         //clear input row
    }  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yes............

Comment: If you are not interested in copying formats, just data, appendRow could be the solution. It's atomic operation, it solves your simultaneous users problem. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents

Comment: @Milan The source and destination column match up and both sheets have the same formating.
I'll give appendRow a go and see how things respond.

Comment: @Cooper question updated.

Comment: _"Would I be better off implementing the use of Lock Service?"_ Yep. Looks promising. I wold try it. Though I never tried it yet, can't say anything.